# Query on Apostol's definition of the derivative of Arithmetical functions

Tags: analytic-number-theory

In Apostol's book "Introduction to Analytic Number Theory", Apostol says:

> For any arithmetical function $f$ we define its derivative $f'$ to be the arithmetical function given by the equation

$$f'(n)=f(n)\log(n) \quad\text{for}\quad n\ge1.$$

**My question is:** He claims the derivative is an arithmetic function, but $\log(n)$ does not always give you a natural number output and an arithmetic function is defined on natural numbers. How can we know that if $f(n)$ is defined for $n$ then $f'(n)$ will also be if it truly is an arithmetic function for all $n$?

Comment: arithmetic functions are of the form $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. This means that you only want the input to always be an integer rather than the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [arithmetic function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticFunction.html) maps the natural numbers to some subset of the complex numbers.

The range of $\log$ is all real numbers and the range of $f$ is, by definition, some subset of the complex numbers. So the function $f'(n)$ defined by a product of a real and complex number will also map to a subset of the complex numbers.